# How to interpret Tensor sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, torch

I'm having difficulty understanding the **difference** between the following:

`x1 = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])  # single brackets`

`x2 = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3]])  # double brackets`

When checking their sizes:
`x1.size()` and `x2.size()` we get the following:

```
torch.Size([3])
torch.Size([1, 3])
```

Which I interpret as `x1` being a (3x1) column vector, while `x2` is a (1x3) row vector.

However, when attempting to transpose both vectors:
`print(x1.T)`
`print(x2.T)`, we get:

```
tensor([1, 2, 3])
tensor([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

`x1` seems to be **unaffected** by transposition?
Further when attempting to force `x1` to be a (1x3) row vector using ".view()":
`print(x1.view(1, -1))` we get:

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3]])  # double brackets
```

So how come ".T" didn't do the trick, but ".view(1, -1)" was able to transform `x1` into a (1x3) row vector?

What really is `x1` when we first assigned it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.t.html) -

> Expects input to be <= 2-D tensor and transposes dimensions 0 and 1.
> 0-D and 1-D tensors are returned as is. When input is a 2-D tensor this is equivalent to transpose(input, 0, 1).

```
x = torch.randn(())
torch.t(x)
#tensor(0.1995)

x = torch.randn(3)
x
#tensor([ 2.4320, -0.4608,  0.7702])

torch.t(x)
#tensor([ 2.4320, -0.4608,  0.7702])

x = torch.randn(2, 3)
x
#tensor([[ 0.4875,  0.9158, -0.5872],
#        [ 0.3938, -0.6929,  0.6932]])

torch.t(x)
#tensor([[ 0.4875,  0.3938],
#        [ 0.9158, -0.6929],
#        [-0.5872,  0.6932]])
```

This is the reason why `x1` has no effect. It's currently a 1D tensor and NOT a 2D tensor. There is a difference between the shape of `(3,)` and `(3,1)`. The first only has a single axis while the other has 2 axis (similar to the double brackets you added)

This statement, `Which I interpret as x1 being a (3x1) column vector, while x2 is a (1x3) row vector.` is incorrect to some extent.

```
x1 #(3,) 1D tensor
x1.reshape((3,1) #(3,1) #2D tensor

x1.T #(1,3) 2D tensor with successful transpose
```

Comment: Brilliant! Though wouldn't the 2nd part of my statement be true? "while x2 is a (1x3) row vector". Also is there any difference between ".view()" and ".reshape()"?

Comment: Yes the second part is true. Difference between view and reshape is that reshape always copies memory while view never copies memory. Both have their pros and cons.